# How do I show the image in a node enlarged?

Tags: 7, media

I use the TinyMCE editor as site's editor. When I publish an image, I want the users click the image to view it enlarged.
How can I do this? The image is not a field; it is an image in the node.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [Image Resize Filter](http://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter)

Here is a nice tutorial by Lullabot: [Effortless Inline Thumbnails: Image Resize Filter](http://www.lullabot.com/videos/effortless-inline-thumbnails-image-resize-filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) and [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox).